# how to save multiple data using array in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, input

this is a part of my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="title[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="f_name[]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Last Name*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="l_name[]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if i click add button, it will show the second form same like above. so how to save all input data into database? this is what i've done in my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $title = $request->title;
    $f_name = $request->f_name;
    $l_name = $request->l_name;

    $form = new Conference;
    $form->name = $title.' '.$f_name.' '.$l_name;
    $form->email = $request->email;
    $form->phone = $request->phone;
    $form->position = $request->position;
    $form->category = $request->optradio;
    $form->price = $request->price;
    $form->t_price = $request->t_price;
    $form->company = $request->company;
    $form->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message','REGISTRATION SUCCESS');
  }
```

but it returned an error "Array to string conversion". I know i have to write something in my controller but i don't know what to do. can someone help me?

Comment: you're getting title, f_name, l_name in array. remove `[]` array. now your name will looks like `title`

Comment: is it ok to remove it? because i want to save multiple form with the same field at once

Comment: add foreach loop before your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through elements and then bulk insert as below

```
public function store(Request $request){

$title = $request->title;
$f_name = $request->f_name;
$l_name = $request->l_name;

$data = [];
foreach($title as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
        "name" => $value." ".$f_name[$key]." ".$l_name[$key];
    ] 
}


  $Conference::insert($data);
  return redirect()->back()->with('message','REGISTRATION SUCCESS');
}
```